# Number of weeks between two flexible dates - PHP

Tags: php

I have been looking through all the previous questions which similar to this question unfortunately   non of them work for me.

I am trying to get the number of weeks between two dates.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE  `DateofTest` BETWEEN  '" .    
$startDate . "' AND  '" . $endDate . "' ") or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

$startDate = $_POST['start'];
$endDate = $POST['end'];
```

Suppose my start date is 01/12/2014 and end date is 31/12/2014 so 4 weeks.

Here is my code

```
   $startDate ="2014-12-01";
   $endDate ="2014-12-31";
   $days=($startDate - $endDate);
     echo $days;
   $weeks=($days / 7);
   echo $weeks;
```

I am getting 0 result for each days and weeks.

Any ideas please.

Thanks

Comment: That is because you are calculating with strings, not dates,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare date strings and expect to get the difference.
You should use the DateTime class to compare two datetime values:

```
$startDate = new DateTime("2014-12-01");
$endDate = new DateTime("2014-12-31");
$diff = $startDate->diff( $endDate )->format('%d');
$weeks = floor($diff/7);
```

`format` method can return a difference in a number of ways like years/months/days/hours/minutes/seconds. More [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a function for some reason I can't get it work when I put it in a function. $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE Date BETWEEN '" . $startDate . "' AND '" . $endDate . "' ") or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con)); function getNumberofWeeks($startDate , $endDate) { $startDate = $_POST['start']; $endDate = $_POST['end']; $diffweek = abs(strtotime($startDate) - strtotime($endDate)) / 604800; return round($diffweek); }

Answer (score 4):

You can't calculate strings. You need to convert them to dates.
You can do something like:

```
function get_number_of_weeks($startDate, $endDate) {
    // use strtotime and substract the end date from the start date, not the otherway around
    $days = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate);

    // devide by seconds / hours and weeks
    $weeks = $days / 3600 / 24 / 7;
    // floor the amount of weeks.
    return floor($weeks);
}

echo get_number_of_weeks("2014-12-01", "2014-12-31");
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a function so would be something like that function getnumberofweeks ($startDate , $endDate) {$days = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate);

// devide by seconds / hours and weeks
$weeks = $days / 3600 / 24 / 7; return floor ($weeks)  } ?

Comment: I test with my code as function not getting any result :(        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE  `DateofTest` BETWEEN  '" . $startDate . "' AND  '" . $endDate . "' ") or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
    
       function getNumberofWeeks($startDate, $endDate) {
      
        $days = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate);
        // devide by seconds / hours and weeks
        $weeks = $days / 3600 / 24 / 7;
        // floor the amount of weeks.
       return floor($weeks);
    }

Comment: You need to pass your variables to the function I guess?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what i am trying to do

Answer (score 4):

Something like this using  the date time object will work

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2014-12-01");
$d2 = new DateTime("2014-12-31");
$difference_in_days = $d1->diff($d2)->days;

echo "Diff in Weeks = ".$difference_in_days/7;
```

Comment: I test your code. Not correct.I got Diff in Weeks = 4.2857142857143.

Comment: Thats correct, 31 days difference is 4.28 weeks if you want it in figures your more familiar then round down using floor() that way it'll say "4 weeks" rather than 4.2

Comment: @EmJad this is surely correct. You just need to ignore any decimal points

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    <?php

    $d1 ="2014-12-01";
       $d2 ="2014-12-31";

    $diffweek = abs(strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2)) / 604800;
    echo round($diffweek); or echo intval($diffweek);
  ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a function for some reason I can't get it work when I put it in a function.       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE  `Date` BETWEEN  '" . $startDate . "' AND  '" . $endDate . "' ") or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
    
 
    function getNumberofWeeks($startDate , $endDate)
 {
   $startDate = $_POST['start'];
   $endDate = $_POST['end'];
     $diffweek = abs(strtotime($startDate) - strtotime($endDate)) / 604800;
     return round($diffweek); 
  
  }